# Turn off Control Center in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, settings, control-center

Is there a way to turn off the control center in macOS Big Sur? In settings under dock and menu bar there are settings to the control center but no option to disable it.

Comment: What insanity. You can disable the other menu bar options, but not this. If you want to avoid duplication you're essentially forced to use only control center, which hides everything behind a click and occasionally 2 seconds of loading time.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to turn off the control center in macOS Big Sur?

### No.

That's not available on Ventura neither.

Although you cannot disable Control Center altogether, you can disable certain elements of it as explained in [Change Control Centre settings on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlad96d366/13.0/mac/13.0):

> On your Mac, use Control Centre settings to choose which items to include in Control Centre and which items appear in the menu bar. [Learn how to use Control Centre](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/quickly-change-settings-mchl50f94f8f/13.0/mac/13.0)

As explained in the aforementioned article, here are the "Other Modules", which can be removed:

> - Accessibility Shortcuts
> - Battery
> - Hearing
> - Fast User Switching
> - Keyboard Brightness

Those could be removed (on macOS Ventura) by going to *System Settings > Control Centre* and disabling the "Show in Control Centre" option.